# Keep getting a 404 when using Ajax in drupal

Tags: json, drupal, jquery

Hello i've got this problem with an ajax call in my (newbie) Drupal site. I'm trying to save some data from a form field, by posting it with jQuery to a function in my Drupal module. Here is my code:

```
// in drupal
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['mymodule/set/data'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_set_data',
        'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
    return $items;
}
function mymodule_set_data($var) {
    drupal_json_output(array('status' => 'OK', 'data' => "return_something"));
}

// in my js file
jQuery("#form_element").on('blur',function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "mymodule/set/data",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
      fu: 'bar'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Everything goes well, the jQuery get's triggerd, the ajax call is being catched on the server, and i do get the {"status":"OK","data":"return_something"} back from the server. Except for the fact that the status of the call is a 404... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an solution to my problem.

Ik was moving my app to an other host and there for i needed to change the url the ajax action was calling. I decided to make it dynamic with the following code:

```
drupal_add_js(array('url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'setting');
```

I changed my ajax call url into:
"http://"+Drupal.settings.url + "/set/data

This resulted in my JS calling the following URL:
http://host/drupal/?q=mymodule/set/data
instead of the old one:
http://host/drupal/mymodule/set/data

Which was something Drupal did like :)

Still i don't understand why my drupal accepted http://host/drupal/mymodule/set/data, handled my data but returned a 404.